# Spotlight Importer in Xcode 6. Up to date documentation?

Tags: plugins, xcode6, spotlight

I need to develop a spotlight importer for a custom data type on Xcode 6

The online apple documentation seems quite comprehensive, and there is also a nice example project [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SpotlightFortunes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007773). Only problem is, when I create a new Spotlight Importer project in Xcode 6, the template doesn't look at all like anything described in the official docs. For example, there's no *schema.xml* file, there is different and obscure terminology like *store file uti*, *external record uti*, etc.

It looks like the apple docs are seriously out of date. Can anybody provide some help? A link to some third party tutorial or example project?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation isn't really out of date. It's just that the template in Xcode 6 assumes your application uses Core Data. You can find details in the **Core Data Spotlight Integration Programming Guide**.

However, you can pretty easily adapt the project created from the Spotlight Importer template so that it lets you create a *normal* importer. I recently did this in order to write an importer that processed Lua source files so that I could use Spotlight to search for particular functions, etc.

If you were going to create lots of importers, you could create a custom template that has the following fixes applied. But I'm not, so I didn't...

Create a new project using the Spotlight Importer template and then:

1. Remove `MySpotlightImporter.{h, m}`
2. Gut the implementation of `GetMetadataForFile()` in `GetMetadataForFile.m`
3. Add `schema.xml` and `schema.strings` using the Empty file template
4. Edit `Info.plist` to correctly describe your Exported Type UTIs (*if any*).

You can find the details on `schema.xml` in Apple's documentation. Now you *just* need to implement `GetMetadataForFile()` so that it behaves appropriately for your custom file format.